# What is the difference between $obj = 'classname' and $obj = new classname()

Tags: php

Hi friends could you please clarify what is the difference in the following piece of code:

```
<?php
class student {
    function stu() {
        echo "Hi Friends";
    }
}

//difference between this
$s = new student();
$s -> stu();

//and this
$s1 = 'student';
$s1 -> stu();
```

What is the difference between `$s = new student();` and `$s1 = 'student';`

Answer (score 4):

`$s = new student();` creates a new instance of class `student` and stores it into the `$s` variable.

`$s1 = 'student';` stores the string `student` into the variable `$s1`. The last line `$s1->stu();` gives an error, since you can`t call methods on string.

My suggestion for you would be to get a beginner PHP book and read it, so you will master the basics.

Comment: Thanks Jan Hancic surly I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

you must have meant:

```
$instance = new myclass();
```

and

```
$type = 'myclass';
$instance = new $type;
```

If this is what you meant, then there are no differences. The later is used when you want your classnames to be generated dynamically.